# Fullcalendar React Retrieving events & resources asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

If the list of resources is derived from the current viewable list of events, how to modify both at the same time.

Current you can either use a function in the `events` or `resources` fields. But in my use case, the data to fill both are retrieved from the same query.

I tried with the `datesRender` but that causes a render loop.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Ok so first question: _why_ is the list of resources derived from the current list of events? It seems a slightly strange requirement.

Comment: One suggestion though: If you are fetching your resources from a JSON feed (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed), and your events in the same way (per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) then you can set "refetchResourcesOnNavigate" to true. This will mean every time you fetch events, it will also fetch resources, and it will send the current start/end dates of the calendar to the resources endpoint.

Comment: That way your server code can return a set of resources using the same parameters it uses to return a set of events. (Which means, it can get the event data for those dates, and then process them in order to derive the correct list of resources, before returning that list to the calendar.)

Comment: The 'events' i request store the 'resources', in my case their category, and given there could be hundreds of categories, many of which could be empty within the timespan currently being viewed it doesn't make sense to render all.

Comment: Ok. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/filterResourcesWithEvents might also be useful in that kind of situation. Have a good look through the documentation and see what might be helpful to you.

Comment: I'm using graphql which allows me to get relevant resources as subqueries of the events within the given timespan. Otherwise I would have to query all the resources, and let the fullcalendar filter them. It is a possible solution but seems unnecessary, if only a fraction of the resources are visible at any given time.

Comment: ok well see my second and third comments above, that's how you can filter the resources before sending them to the calendar.